# Group by values and merging child elements from xml using xslt 1.0

Tags: xslt

I am new to XSLT and changing it manually will take a lot of time.Pleases help me convert xml to xml using xslt 1.0 and provide details.  I dont find group by and merging values belongs two differrent nodes.

```
      <MTR>
           <program>
        <row>
        <rep_number>001</rep_number>
        <program_id>PMP</program_id>
        <name>Program 1</name>
        <acct_no> 2001 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
        </row>

        <row>
        <rep_number>002</rep_number>
        <program_id>CSP</program_id>
        <name>Program 2 </name>
        <acct_no> 2002 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
        </row>

        <row>
        <rep_number>001</rep_number>
        <program_id>PMP</program_id>
        <name>Program 1</name>
        <acct_no> 2003 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
        </row>

        <row>
        <rep_number>001</rep_number>
        <program_id>PMP</program_id>
        <name>Program 1</name>
        <acct_no> 2004 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
       </row>           
    </program>
      </MTR>


    **expecting output:**

    <reports>
        <report>
        <rep_number>001</rep_number>
        <program_id>PMP</program_id>
        <name>Program 1</name>
        <acct_no> 2001,2003,2004 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
        </report>

       <report>

        <rep_number>002</rep_number>
        <program_id>CSP</program_id>
        <name>Program 2 </name>
        <acct_no> 2002 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
       </report>

    </reports>
```

Comment: If I understand correctly you will need to do some Muenchian grouping. Read up on these answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=muenchian%20isaccepted%3ayes. Otherwise, you need to update your question to show what you've tried and/or what output you are wanting to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following template. Explanations are within comments.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>    

    <!-- create a key using a combination of 'rep_number', 'program_id', and 'name' -->

    <xsl:key name="kGroup" match="row" use="concat(rep_number, '+', program_id, '+', name)"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <reports>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </reports>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="program">
        <!-- I have used the second method in 
            http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.xml 
            in testing whether two nodes are identical -->
        <xsl:for-each select="row[count(. | key('kGroup', concat(rep_number, '+', program_id, '+', name))[1]) = 1]">
            <report>
                <!-- copy the nodes -->
                <xsl:copy-of select="rep_number"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="program_id"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="name"/>
                <acct_no>
                <!-- loop through key matches -->
                <xsl:for-each select="key('kGroup', concat(rep_number, '+', program_id, '+', name))">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <!-- checks for position, if 
                            its the last in the group, then
                            do not insert a comma -->
                        <xsl:when test="position()!=last()">
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(acct_no)"/><xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(acct_no)"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:for-each>
                </acct_no>
                <xsl:copy-of select="value"/>
            </report>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

when this is applied to your input XML, it outputs:

```
<reports>

   <report>
      <rep_number>001</rep_number>
      <program_id>PMP</program_id>
      <name>Program 1</name>
      <acct_no>2001,2003,2004</acct_no>
      <value>150</value>
   </report>
   <report>
      <rep_number>002</rep_number>
      <program_id>CSP</program_id>
      <name>Program 2 </name>
      <acct_no>2002</acct_no>
      <value>150</value>
   </report>

</reports>
```

Comment: Hi Joel M. Lamsen, Thanks for your answer. But my case is I have to group only particular program_id.

Comment: Hi Joel M. Lamsen, Thanks for your answer. But my case is I have to group and merge only particular program_id(Example: only porgram_id=PMP and acct_number belongs to PMP should be separated by comma)

Comment: **expecting output:**

    <reports>
        <report>
        <rep_number>001</rep_number>
        <program_id>PMP</program_id>
        <name>Program 1</name>
        <acct_no> 2001,2003,2004 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
        </report>

       <report>

        <rep_number>002</rep_number>
        <program_id>CSP</program_id>
        <name>Program 2 </name>
        <acct_no> 2002 </acct_no>
        <value>150</value>
       </report>

    </reports>

Comment: **expecting output:**
    <reports>
        <report>
        <rep_number>001</rep_number>
        <program_id>PMP</program_id>
        <name>Pro 1</name>
        <acct_no> 2001,2003,2004 </acct_no>        
        </report>

       <report>
        <rep_number>002</rep_number>
        <program_id>CSP</program_id>
        <name>Pro 2 </name>
        <acct_no> 2002 </acct_no>        
       </report>
        <rep_number>003</rep_number>
        <program_id>CSP</program_id>
        <name>Pro 2 </name>
        <acct_no> 2005 </acct_no>        
       </report>
    </reports>

Comment: Hi Joel M. Lamsen, I modified your code and got expected output. Thanks for your support.

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow! If you find the answer useful, kindly accept the answer by clicking the check mark to the left of the answer (just below the arrowheads). This way other users can see that the answer is the right answer. It is also one way of saying thanks.

Comment: I found that the Muenchian grouping is not working in few environment. Please update anybody what went wrong..